# Only the first letter of a product description appears in zen cart

Tags: zen-cart

I'm working on this zen cart site. [A Love Supreme Shop](http://www.alsshop.co.uk/index.php?main_page=products_new)
In new and featured listings only the first letter of the product description appears whether I use a custom template or the default. I'm using 1.3.9 but the data has come from a 1.3.0 site.

When product descriptions are shown on all products they show up fine.
Is the description being put into an array incorrectly and only the first element of the array being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin->configuration->new listing, and look at the value of Display Product Description.  I wonder if yours is 0.  It should be 120 or 150.  If you don't see this setting, your database is missing values.

Failing that look at the file

includes/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/templates/tpl_modules_products_new_listing.php

and see how description is being handled.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Scott that helped me get to the root of the problem :

On my admin->configuration->new listing->Display Product Description page there is no textbox to change the number of characters displayed.

There is only a question :

Do you want to display the Product Description - First 150 characters?
Followed by the options 0 = off and 1 = on

I checked another zen cart running on another server and it has the textbox to change the number of characters.

I followed your instructions to look at :

includes/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/templates/tpl_modules_products_new_listing.php

I edited the code that displays the product description replacing the value PRODUCT_NEW_LIST_DESCRIPTION with 150.

This worked.

However the underlying problem is solved here :

[Solution on Zen Cart Forum](http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?t=95869)

SELECT *
FROM `configuration`
WHERE `configuration_title` = 'display product description';

This returns 4 records

Changing configuration_value from 1 to 150
Changing configuration_description from :
Do you want to display the Product Description - First 150 
characters?

to :

Do you want to display the Product Description?
0= OFF
150= Suggested Length, or enter the maximum number of characters to display

and changing the set_function from :

zen_cfg_select_option(array('0', '1'),

to :

NULL

Thanks for the assistance @Scott Wilson.
Still don't know the route cause of the problem. Probably not migrating the database properly.